# How to pass functions as props to components and call them without using arrow notation in React+Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a function, `selectMarket()`, which I'm passing as a prop to a component, `AssetSelectorRow`. In the `AssetSelectorRow`, I'm assigning the function to be called during an `onClick` event.

If I use `onClick={selectMarket(asset)}`, I get the following error:

```
Type 'void' is not assignable to type '((event: MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement, MouseEvent>) => void) | undefined'.  TS2322
```

If I use `onClick={() => selectMarket(asset)}`, then everything works as intended, but I'd like to avoid this notation as it unnecessarily renders a new callback on each render. I'm also just curious as to why the former doesn't work.

```
const selectMarket = (market: IPositionListItem) => {
  if (
    currentSymbol.base.id !== market.base ||
    currentSymbol.quote.id !== market.counter
  ) {
    setSelectedMarket(market);
  }
};

<AssetSelectorRow
  key={asset.name}
  asset={asset}
  selectMarket={selectMarket}
/>
```

**AssetSelectorRow.js**:

```
interface IOwnProps {
  asset: IPositionListItem;
  selectMarket: (asset: IPositionListItem) => void;

export const AssetSelectorRow = memo(({ asset, selectMarket }: IOwnProps) => {
  return (
    <div
      className="bp3-button-group bp3-fill bp3-minimal menu-item-group"
      key={asset.name}
      onClick={selectMarket(asset)}
    >
      Asset
    </div>
  );
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is correct, because the expected signature of the click event handler does not match your actual handler.

You **might** adjust your function as follows:

```
const selectMarket = (event: MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement, MouseEvent>, market: IPositionListItem) => {
  if (
    currentSymbol.base.id !== market.base ||
    currentSymbol.quote.id !== market.counter
  ) {
    setSelectedMarket(market);
  }
};
```

but now the problem is:

> how to pass the second argument (market) to the function?

the `onClick` event does not do that for you.

Thus, the only way to correctly handle your function is via indirect handler call, as you already figured it out:

`onClick={() => selectMarket(asset)}`

it works because the signature simply drops the expected argument (event), but that's not in conflict to anything.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the detailed explanation